# How to pass arguments to a batch file running an application with these arguments?

Tags: batch-file

The command below is in a batch file named `D:\vlcplay.bat`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --play-and-exit --start-time=25 --run-time=5 --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue "C:\Test Files\test.mp4" --video-filter --ignore-config
```

I want to call this batch file by passing it three variables in place of `25` after `--start-time`, `5` after `--run-time` and file name `"C:\Test Files\test.mp4"`.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I suggest using `"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --play-and-exit --start-time=%~2 --run-time=%~3  --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue "%~1"  --video-filter --ignore-config`. But I recommend to add extra lines to test if there is at least one argument passed to the batch file (the MP4 file to process) and use defaults if second argument (start time) and/or third argument (run time) are not passed to the batch file on calling it.

Comment: Thank a Ton, Mofi. That was very helpful. I could do what I wanted with those inputs. And so much to learn.